# Deploying roots/bedrock to WPEngine

Tags: git, deployment, shared-hosting, theme-roots

### Overview

I am to establish a robust WordPress Development Process utilizing the following tools:

- [WPEngine](https://wpengine.com/)
- [roots/bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/)
- [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions)

The goal is to deploy the entire site, including the WordPress core and plugins. I'm using Composer to handle this task.

### Challenges

I'm currently facing two primary challenges:

1. **WPEngine Directive Limitation**:

   - WPEngine support informed me that they do not allow modifications to the `root` directive. However, they mentioned that rule rewrites or additions are permissible, citing the example of rules for the `webp optimizer` plugin.
2. **GitHub Action Error**:

   - During the GitHub Action process, I encounter an error that says:

```
'wp-config.php' not found.
Either create one manually or use 'wp config create'
```

- It's puzzling since the `bedrock` setup has a `wp-cli.yml` configuration pointing to a different path:

  ```yml
  path: web/wp
  server:
    docroot: web
  ```

#### GitHub Action Configuration

Here's my current GitHub Action setup:

```yml
name: Deploy to WPE Production Environment 
on:
  push:
    branches:
     - main
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    steps: 
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: php-actions/composer@v6
    - name: Deploy to WP Engine
      uses: wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy@v3
      with:
        WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE: ${{ secrets.WPE_KEY }} 
        WPE_ENV: example
        SRC_PATH: ""
        REMOTE_PATH: ""
        PHP_LINT: FALSE
        FLAGS: -azvr --inplace --delete --exclude=".*" --exclude-from=.deployignore
        CACHE_CLEAR: TRUE
```

### Local Development Experience

For local WordPress project development, I rely on the `Local by FlyWheel` tool. This allows for an easy change of the `root` directive:

```
root   "{{root}}";
root   "{{root}}/web";
```

However, my attempt to rewrite the `root` directive led to a **502** error:

```
server {
    listen {{port}};
    root {{root}};
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri @new_root;
    }
    
    location @new_root {
        rewrite ^ /web$uri;
    }
}
```

### Research & Possible Solutions

Though I've scoured numerous resources to alter the direction of `wp-config`, I haven't found a viable solution yet. I'm open to suggestions.

One thought is to potentially craft a custom deployment script to bridge `WPE & Bedrock`.

### Additional References

- WPE Action site deploy (by an external author): [Link](https://github.com/linchpin/action-wpengine-deploy)
- WPE Action site deploy: [Link](https://github.com/wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy)
- Older deployment script from 2016 for themes: [Link](https://github.com/hello-jason/bedrock-deploy-to-wpengine)

Any input or assistance would be greatly appreciated.